# QLDB query error with operator less than or equal to

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-qldb

i do the next query:

```
select * from TableName As t where t.number <= 34
```

but i get the next error:

Lexer Error: at line 3, column 75: invalid character at, '&' [U+26]; (Service: AmazonQLDBSession; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 96Eijm2iiOGHw9cS8J5rve; Proxy: null)

and the estatement error is `&lt;= 10`
someone knows what happens??

Comment: SELECT * FROM TableName AS t WHERE t.number <= 34. Fixed your query or may be that was a typo?

Comment: @Asdfg nop the typo is &lt;=

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are running this on the Amazon QLDB console.

Looks like there is a bug in our Console. I have raised this issue with the team and we are working on the fix. Thanks for bringing this up! We will update the thread when it is fixed. Please note that the statement will execute fine if you run it using the [official drivers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/getting-started-driver.html).

Update:

The console issue has been fixed.

Comment: thanks for your help I thought that without it it did not work in the console except in the driver

Comment: Can you share the code snippet and the error please ?